# Unable to push children into parent based on parentId using JS

Tags: javascript

I am unable to push childEntries into parent based on parentId using JS. Actually I need to populate the data into a tree view table.

Here is the JSON I got from API

```
[{
    "displayName": "",
    "order": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "description": "Application Top Section",
    "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "parentId": 0,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "id": 0,
    "type": "section"
}, {
    "displayName": "",
    "order": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "description": "Application Side Navigation Section",
    "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "parentId": 1,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "id": 1,
    "type": "section"
}, {
    "displayName": "Puente Dashboard",
    "order": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "description": "Application Dashboard",
    "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "parentId": 1,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "id": 2,
    "type": "link"
}, {
    "displayName": "Security",
    "order": 2,
    "status": "Active",
    "description": "Security Management",
    "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "parentId": 1,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "id": 3,
    "type": "link"
}, {
    "displayName": "User",
    "order": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "description": "User Management",
    "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "parentId": 3,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "id": 4,
    "type": "link"
}, {
    "displayName": "Role",
    "order": 2,
    "status": "Active",
    "description": "Role Management",
    "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "parentId": 3,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "id": 5,
    "type": "link"
}, {
    "displayName": "Widget",
    "order": 3,
    "status": "Active",
    "description": "Widget Management",
    "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "parentId": 3,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
    "id": 6,
    "type": "link"
}]
```

And expected JSON is

```
[{
        "displayName": "",
        "order": 1,
        "status": "Active",
        "description": "Application Top Section",
        "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
        "parentId": 0,
        "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
        "id": 0,
        "type": "section"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "",
        "order": 1,
        "status": "Active",
        "description": "Application Side Navigation Section",
        "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
        "parentId": 1,
        "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
        "id": 1,
        "type": "section",
        "childEntries": [{
                "displayName": "Puente Dashboard",
                "order": 1,
                "status": "Active",
                "description": "Application Dashboard",
                "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                "parentId": 1,
                "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                "id": 2,
                "type": "link"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "Security",
                "order": 2,
                "status": "Active",
                "description": "Security Management",
                "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                "parentId": 1,
                "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                "id": 3,
                "type": "link",
                "childEntries": [{
                        "displayName": "User",
                        "order": 1,
                        "status": "Active",
                        "description": "User Management",
                        "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                        "parentId": 3,
                        "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                        "id": 4,
                        "type": "link"
                    },
                    {
                        "displayName": "Role",
                        "order": 2,
                        "status": "Active",
                        "description": "Role Management",
                        "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                        "parentId": 3,
                        "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                        "id": 5,
                        "type": "link"
                    },
                    {
                        "displayName": "Widget",
                        "order": 3,
                        "status": "Active",
                        "description": "Widget Management",
                        "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                        "parentId": 3,
                        "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
                        "id": 6,
                        "type": "link"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Using below code only I am able to add "kind","childEntries" and "expanded". But ultimately I am not getting my expected JSON.

this.widgetsource.forEach(function (element) { if(element.parentId == 1 || element.parentId == 0 ){ element.kind = "dir"; element.expanded = false; element.childEntries = []; }

Here in this.widgetsource I have stored the raw JSON.

Could you please help me here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Last 3 weeks fighting with this. Using below code only I am able to add kind and child Entries. But ultimately I am not getting my expected JSON.
this.widgetsource.forEach(function (element) {
        if(element.parentId == 1 || element.parentId == 0 ){
        element.kind = "dir";
        element.expanded = false;
        element.childEntries = [];
        }
Here in this.widgetsource I ave stored the raw JSON

Comment: better add your attempt in your question itself.

Comment: Yes, I have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if its a child when parent is not equal to itself, then find the parent and add in child list.

```js
    const parsedObject = JSON.parse(`[{ "displayName": "", "order": 1, "status": "Active", "description": "Application Top Section", "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "parentId": 0, "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "id": 0, "type": "section" }, { "displayName": "", "order": 1, "status": "Active", "description": "Application Side Navigation Section", "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "parentId": 1, "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "id": 1, "type": "section" }, { "displayName": "Puente Dashboard", "order": 1, "status": "Active", "description": "Application Dashboard", "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "parentId": 1, "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "id": 2, "type": "link" }, { "displayName": "Security", "order": 2, "status": "Active", "description": "Security Management", "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "parentId": 1, "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "id": 3, "type": "link" }, { "displayName": "User", "order": 1, "status": "Active", "description": "User Management", "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "parentId": 3, "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "id": 4, "type": "link" }, { "displayName": "Role", "order": 2, "status": "Active", "description": "Role Management", "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "parentId": 3, "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "id": 5, "type": "link" }, { "displayName": "Widget", "order": 3, "status": "Active", "description": "Widget Management", "createDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "parentId": 3, "modifiedDate": "2020-01-01 12:00:00", "id": 6, "type": "link" }]`);
    
    /**
     * converting into a map for efficient access by ID id:Object.
     */
    const idMap = parsedObject.reduce((accum,obj)=>{
        accum[obj.id] = obj;
        return accum;
    },{});

    const categorisedList = [];    
    parsedObject.forEach(obj=>{
        if(obj.parentId === obj.id){
            categorisedList.push(obj);
        }else{
            const parent = idMap[obj.parentId];
            if(!parent.childEntries){
                parent.childEntries=[];
            }
            parent.childEntries.push(obj);
        }
    });
    console.log(categorisedList);
    //If you need as JSON String.
    const json = JSON.stringify(categorisedList);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is working for me. Only it  will be helpful if you could explan me below lines of code.

    const idMap = parsedObject.reduce((accum,obj)=>{
        accum[obj.id] = obj;
        return accum;
    },{});